# Why is my code mutating the contents of a list in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate all permutations for a given set. On each callback of my code, the contents of the array change for some reason, when I am using the append function. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
class Solution(object):
    def permute(self, nums):
        res = []
        self.generate_permutations(nums, res, 0, len(nums)-1)
        return res

    def generate_permutations(self, nums, res, l, r):
        if l == r:
            res.append(nums)

        for i in range(l, r+1):
            nums[i], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[i]
            print('res', res)
            self.generate_permutations(nums, res, l+1, r)
            nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
```

Comment: By the way, `return res.append` is going to return `None` and you never capture the recursive return value, but `itertools` is your friend, and you should learn that method to make permutations

Comment: Lists are passed by reference.

Comment: @cricket_007 no idea why i had return res.append in there. But im not using itertools because this is for algorthm study. Its generating the permutations correctly, but theres a python gotcha thats changing the values

Comment: How can something be "correct", but also "changing values"?

Comment: Pass a copy of `nums`, not `nums` itself. Lists are mutable and are passed by reference. Why are you surprised that your mutating code mutates the list you pass it?

Comment: @cricket_007 If you run the program with any input, on each callback, the values in the list are being changed for some reason. The permutation orderings are correct, so for example on first call: res can be [1,2,3] and then for some reason on the next call, it gets mutated to [[1,3,2], [1,3,2]] and then next call it gets mutated to [[2,1,3],[2,1,3],[2,1,3]]

Comment: Do what John said. You are swapping elements of a list, then appending that same list to `res`.

Comment: Is there a workaround other than saying a = nums[:] and creating a copy everytime the function is called?

Comment: Why are you objecting to creating a copy each time?  Do you want n-references to the same permutation in your list, or n distinct permutations?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simplified generator will make the problem clearer:

```
def gen(num):
    for i in range(3):
        num.append(i)
        yield num
```

It generates a growing list:

```
In [119]: g=gen([])
In [121]: next(g)
Out[121]: [0]
In [122]: next(g)
Out[122]: [0, 1]
In [123]: next(g)
Out[123]: [0, 1, 2]
```

But if I collect the results in a list, I get repeats

```
In [125]: [i for i in gen([])]
Out[125]: [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Instead I need to collect copies

```
In [126]: [i[:] for i in gen([])]
Out[126]: [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

The repeats may be more obvious if I look at the `id` of each element

```
In [129]: [id(i) for i in alist]
Out[129]: [2881121580, 2881121580, 2881121580]
```

or if I modify one element of the list (and end up modifying all)

```
In [130]: alist[0].append(10)
In [131]: alist
Out[131]: [[0, 1, 2, 10], [0, 1, 2, 10], [0, 1, 2, 10]]
```

=================

With your function, saving `nums[:]` to `res`:

```
def generate_permutations(nums, res, l, r):
        if l == r:
            res.append(nums[:])        # <=== change
        for i in range(l, r+1):
            nums[i], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[i]
            generate_permutations(nums, res, l+1, r)
            nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
In [158]: res=[];nums=[1,2,3]
In [159]: generate_permutations(nums, res,0,2)
In [160]: res
Out[160]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```